# Inverse laplace e^-s/(s(s+1))

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, laplace-transform, differential

Find inverse laplace transform of the following:

> $$L^{-1}\{{\frac{e^{-s}}{s(s+1)}}\}$$

I have try to decompose the fraction into

$$\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s+1}$$

now $e^{-s}$ as numerator is new for me, may I know how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the $e^{-s}$ alone. We see $$\frac{e^{-s}}{s(s+1)} = e^{-s} \left(\frac{1}{s(s+1)} \right) = e^{-s}\left(\frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s+1} \right) = \frac{e^{-s}}{s} - \frac{e^{-s}}{s+1}.$$ Now you can take the inverse transform of the two terms separately.